# Array Collection Error While presist document Symfony2.8

Tags: mongodb, symfony

I have Some field in my documents type of "Collection". So when I am     trying to save document I am getting following error.

```
 " Collection type requires value of type array or null, Doctrine\Common    \Collections\ArrayCollection given. even All the field which are collection types are defined as :"

$byLedgersArrays = array(0=>112,1=>566);    
$document->addToLedgers($byLedgersArrays);

//My Document is this:
/**
 * @var array $byLedgers
 *
 * @ODM\Field(name="byLedgers", type="collection")
 */
protected $byLedgers;
public function __construct()
{
    $this->setIsDeleted(false);       
    $this->byLedgers = new ArrayCollection();
}
//Controller:
$document = new Voucher();
$document->addByLedgers($byLedgersArrays);
```

Please help what is missing in this.

Comment: so mongoDB mapping type 'collection' and doctrine's 'arrayCollecction' are not compatible?  http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-mongodb-odm/en/latest/reference/basic-mapping.html#doctrine-mapping-types says its a conversion from php array type to mongoDB collection type

Comment: you could write your own custom mapping types.

Comment: $this->byLedgers = new ArrayCollection(); This need to Convert into :
$this->byLedgers = []; then its working fine. thanks